# div inside HTML <td> tag ? (Bootstrrap 4)

Tags: html, html-table, bootstrap-4

Is it correct to have multiple `<div>` inside a `<td>` tag in a table with bootstrap in the present case even if it's purely a HTML question?
If not what is the correct way to have the description of the dish below it as I don't think putting the description in another `<td>` would be correct.

````
                  <div class="col">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="col" colspan="3" class="menuDishType text-center">Antipasti</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">1</th>
                            <td>
                                <div class="menuDish">Bruschetta Mista</div>
                                <div class="menuDishDescription">(pain toasté, tomates fraîches, huile d’olive, ail, basilic et mozzarella di bufala)</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>13,00€</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">2</th>
                            <td>
                                <div class="menuDish">Crocchetta Di Fromaggio E Parma</div>
                                <div class="menuDishDescription">(croquette de fromage et jambon de Parme)</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>14,00€</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">3</th>
                            <td>
                                <div class="menuDish">Carpaccio Di Manzo Rucola E Grana</div>
                                <div class="menuDishDescription">(assiette de légumes)</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>16,00€</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">4</th>
                            <td>
                                <div class="menuDish">Piatto Di Verdure</div>
                                <div class="menuDishDescription">(assiette de légumes)</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>16,00€</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">5</th>
                            <td>
                                <div class="menuDish">Scampi A Scelta</div>
                                <div class="menuDishDescription">(scampi au choix : à l’ail, à la diable ou aux légumes) - 6 pièces</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>16,00€</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">6</th>
                            <td>
                                <div class="menuDish">Fantasia Dello Chef – 2 Pers.</div>
                                <div class="menuDishDescription">(assortiment d’entrées chaudes/froides, selon l’humeur du chef)</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>19,00€</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                  </div>
              </div> ```
````

Comment: You can validate your HTML using [any validation tool](https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Yes, I did. but the validator doesn't correct everything and I wasn't sure it was good practice to do so. Thank you for your input :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use your way. But also you can use separate divs for your rows instead of a table. It depends on your project. You can use buttons divs images etc inside table rows

Comment: Thank you for your input, I must use a table for this exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple  inside a  tag and it is `normal` way to implement.

I have just verified your HTML in https://validator.w3.org (many customers require run this tool to check `HTML/CSS/JS` file), it not show issue about HTML syntax.

```html
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <div class="col">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="col" colspan="3" class="menuDishType text-center">Antipasti</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">1</th>
                            <td>
                                <div class="menuDish">Bruschetta Mista</div>
                                <div class="menuDishDescription">(pain toasté, tomates fraîches, huile d’olive, ail, basilic et mozzarella di bufala)</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>13,00€</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">2</th>
                            <td>
                                <div class="menuDish">Crocchetta Di Fromaggio E Parma</div>
                                <div class="menuDishDescription">(croquette de fromage et jambon de Parme)</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>14,00€</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">3</th>
                            <td>
                                <div class="menuDish">Carpaccio Di Manzo Rucola E Grana</div>
                                <div class="menuDishDescription">(assiette de légumes)</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>16,00€</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">4</th>
                            <td>
                                <div class="menuDish">Piatto Di Verdure</div>
                                <div class="menuDishDescription">(assiette de légumes)</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>16,00€</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">5</th>
                            <td>
                                <div class="menuDish">Scampi A Scelta</div>
                                <div class="menuDishDescription">(scampi au choix : à l’ail, à la diable ou aux légumes) - 6 pièces</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>16,00€</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">6</th>
                            <td>
                                <div class="menuDish">Fantasia Dello Chef – 2 Pers.</div>
                                <div class="menuDishDescription">(assortiment d’entrées chaudes/froides, selon l’humeur du chef)</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>19,00€</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, happy to hear that it's a normal practice. I wasn't sure it was the correct way.